# Magento 1.7.0.2 Image does not exist

Tags: magento, csv, import

i am import bulk images to the mogento i had the error "Image does not exist" i am trying the fallowing

1)products folder placed at `/media/catalog/product/` and also create a folder import  at media `media/import`

2)csv file is convert into UTF-8 format

3)image name in csv file is like this `/media/catalog/product/products/91803_1_201081211141.jpg`

quid me for better solution

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288171/magento-image-does-not-exist/36401693#36401693) is solution, it will help you.

Answer (score 5):

You should place your images in `media/import` i.e. `media/import/photo.jpg` then in your csv file you just use `photo.jpg`

Comment: Thanks Jürgen. I just fixed it! ;)

Comment: try this show error :Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.

Comment: You need to add a column for the SKU. It is used to identify the products being imported. Also, keep in mind that the first row **must** contain table headers, such as "sku", "name", "image", etc

Answer (score 5):

Tested and working in Magento CE ver. 1.7.0.2

Image: `/media/import/foo.png`
Image name in CSV file:  `/foo.png`

Comment: Using Magento CE 1.8 I needed the leading slash `/foo.png` to get it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you've accidentally deleted a bunch of products but the images are still in the media/catalog/product folder. For example this may happen if you accidentally delete an attribute set because it takes the products with it. Lets say you want to export those products from your staging environment and back into production. You would go into dataflow on staging, do the export and then on production, temporarily change this file:

code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php

Change line 775 to

$arrayToMassAdd, Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product/',

When you're done change it back to

$arrayToMassAdd, Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import',

What this will do is import the product images from where they were. The csv you export from your staging environment will reference image at /l/a/etc etc... so it will work.

Don't forget the '/' at the end of catalog/product