# Magento: "Image does not exist"

Tags: excel, magento, csv, import, magento-1.9

I'm importing a CSV file in Magento (version 1.9).
I receive the error: 'Image does not exist'.
I've tried to do everything I could find on the internet.
The template I'm using for upload is the default template taken from my export folder.

I've added the / before the image name and I've also saved the file as UTF-8 format.

Any advice would help.

Comment: first move all the images in media/import folder and then use '/imagename' in csv and then import. and also give 777 permission to the Import folder...

Comment: I have also found any entry in teh csv that is 'no_selection' will also result in this error, as the importer will try and find an image by that name, and of course fail. Simply remove the 'no_selection' from the csv to resolve

Answer (score 4):

Use advanced profiler 
System > Import/Export > Dataflow – Profiles

You only need to include the attributes that are required, which is just the SKU. Plus the appropiate image attributes. Plus labels if you want to go all out.

When you are creating your new profile, enter the following settings:
[image]

Now you can hit save! With our Profile now complete, we just need to create the folder media/import. This is where you will be storing all your images awaiting import.

When uploading images, they need to be within a folder called media/import. Once saved to that folder you can then reference them relatively. By that I mean if your image is in media/import/test.jpg in your csv reference it as /test.jpg. It’s as easy as that.

Please check this link for more information 
[Import products using csv](http://ashsmith.io/2012/05/importing-product-images-via-csv-in-magento-1-7-0-0/)

**in the Default Import**

**first move all the images in media/import folder and then use '/imagename' in csv and then import.
And give the 777 permission to the import folder.**

Let me know if you have any query....

Answer (score 2):

check 3 point before upload csv file in Magento

1. create  media > import folder and place all images inside import
2. folder import folder should have 777 permission
3. the path of images should be /desert-002.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Your file template must look like this:

`sku,image
product-001,/product_image.jpg`

This file must exist: `yourdocroot/media/import/product_image.jpg`

More detail please read this method:

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::saveImageDataRow`

You will see these lines:

`$imageFile = trim($importData['_media_image']);
$imageFile = ltrim($imageFile, DS);
$imageFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS . $imageFile;`

I hope this help!!!

Answer (score 1):

It may issue with image path in CSV if   a  image path in CSV is abg/test.jpg then it path in Dir is ..media/import/abg/test.jpg.also check image extension letter issue. Suppose your image extension I'd JPG  and you rewrite in CSV is jpg .then it show image not exits